# Get Windows user groups from Active Directory using .net core

Tags: .net-core, active-directory

I try to get a user's groups or users per group using the classes from the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

For example I do this:

```
GroupPrincipal administratorsGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Administrators");
PrincipalCollection pc = administratorsGroup.Members;
```

The problem is that when I try to access a collection of `Members` or `Groups`, I always get an exception with message:

> IDispatch and IDispatchEx are not supported

From this [post](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30011), I understand that these methods/properties are not supported yet and will be implemented in .net core 3.0.

My question is what is the workaround (if exists) to get the Windows groups of a specific user.

Thanks.

Comment: For now, IMO, the best thing is to use some other library like `NovellDirectoryServices` instead of SDS.AM!